# Array literals in JSP Expression Language?

Tags: java, arrays, spring, jsp, el

I've been able to do Array literals in Thymeleaf's expression language before (using...OGNL?...I think...).  Now I am using Spring/JSP.  Do the JSP or Spring Expression Languages support Array Literals?  I can't find any reference to them.

**UPDATE:**
This is basically what I'm trying to do:

```
<c:set var="myUrls" value="${new String[] {
    mk:getUrl(),
    mk:getOtherUrl(),
    mk:getDifferentUrl()
}}" />
```

Comment: share code that is not working for you for clear picture.

Comment: How do you want to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could hack it together in a scriptlet-less way with a little help of maps, `<jsp:useBean>` and EL 2.2.

```html
<jsp:useBean id="map" class="java.util.LinkedHashMap" />
<c:set target="${map}" property="url" value="${mk.url}" />
<c:set target="${map}" property="otherUrl" value="${mk.otherUrl}" />
<c:set target="${map}" property="differentUrl" value="${mk.differentUrl}" />
<c:set var="array" value="${map.values().toArray()}" />

<c:forEach items="${array}" var="item">
    ${item}<br/>
</c:forEach>
```

If your environment doesn't support EL 2.2, just stick to map and access it via the map.

```html
<c:forEach items="${map}" var="entry">
    ${entry.value}<br/>
</c:forEach>
```

Noted should be that your underlying problem is bigger. You shouldn't be manipulating the model directly in the view. The controller is responsible for that. You should be altering the model in such way so that it's exactly what the view expects. E.g. by adding a property, or by letting the controller do the job.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up putting it in the controller, as suggested.

Answer (score 1):

fn:split does it for strings.
Like for tag

```
<tag extraParams="${fn:split('_target1,book', ',')}" />
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use scriptlet to use vanilla Java, in JSP1.x with `<% /* Java */ %>` block, in JSP2 with something like:

```xml
<jsp:scriptlet><![CDATA[
pageContext.setAttribute("myArray", new String[] { "a", "b", "c" });
]]></jsp:scriptlet>

<!-- so then ... -->
${myArray} <!-- or ... -->
<c:forEach items="${myArray}" var="str">
  <p>${str}</p>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: However, the array should certainly be set in some model classes through some business logic, not in JSP.

Comment: Even if theorically that's better not to do it directly in JSP, as soon as it's put in the page context, then it can be resolved by EL expression.